# How to create a login page in node.js which directs to a webpage, that needs to run on the client side with p5.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, p5.js

I have a webpage, which uses p5.js drawing functionality but I want to create a login page so that only users with a username and password can access the page. How do I do this?

Most tutorials have a login page which points to .ejs which I think runs on the server side. I want my login page to point to a normal html page with custom js (this will include p5.js code) but I need this to run on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article to be very clear and simple.
https://codeshack.io/basic-login-system-nodejs-express-mysql/

You can leave out the mysql database stuff and store the usernames and passwords in your own way.

Note that this is a basic example and should not be used in serious applications because it not completely safe. There are node modules available that do it better.

Comment: Thank you- I will look into this.